# Can I select a HTML tag without JavaScript?

Tags: html

I am making a HTML document and I want to put in a button that will show and hide another element. Can that be possible with HTML5?

I tried to first use javascript(but I have a nagging error in my device that does not let me use js) but it didn’t work.

Comment: Your best bet would be the [`<detail>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) tag.

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem and be sure to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, while the solution is a bit limited compared to using JavaScript, it's possible to show and hide elements using HTML5, but you'll also need the help of CSS. While I know you mentioned wanting to use a button, that'd only be possible with JS. You can achieve a basic show/hide function by using the  element with the checkbox type and the adjacent sibling combinator (+) in CSS. Here's an example of how you could do that:

```
 <style>
  /* Hides the target element by default (you can edit this if you want it to initially show) */
  .target {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Hides the checkbox */
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Show the target element when the checkbox is checked */
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .target {
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<label for="toggle">Show/Hide Element</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<div class="target">
  This is the element to show/hide.
</div>
```